# Android - Layout doesn't appear on the device as it appears on the preview

Tags: android, xml, layout

**This is the code of the XML file of the layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.barda.wikirace.MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundmain"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wikiRaceTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/wikiracetop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:id="@+id/twoPlayersBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/twoplayersbutton"
            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"/>




        <Button
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:id="@+id/singlePlayerBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/playbutton"
            android:onClick="startSinglePlayerMenuActivity"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"/>



    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**This is how it looks in the preview:**[image]

**And this is how it appears on the device (LG G4):**
[image]

**What can cause the problem? 
As you can see, I want the buttons to be on the right color for them.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't just use the constraint layout?
if you want to do it in the way you're doing it, you will have to setup the width with a fixed value or match_parent why? because when you say wrap_content and the image is big is going to be over the other views as is happening also you can setup a android:layout_weight for the button if you want to use the weight as "control" for your layout, be coherent with the method that you use to adapt the views.